# How can I find "hidden" colors in an Illustrator document?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, swatches

I made a color group of black and white objects. But it shows 3 different blacks and 1 gray and 1 white color in the swatch. 
How can I isolate or find/see those specific colours that are unwanted in my document? Or how can I delete/remove a specific color from an object? If the color is not to be seen?

Answer (score 2):

With **nothing** selected in the artwork....

- Highlight a swatch in the **Swatch Panel**
- Choose `Select > Same > Fill Color` from the menu
- The objects using that swatch for that fill color will become selected
- Merely click the swatch you *want* to use to replace that color
- Do the same again, de-select all, click the bad swatch... but this time choose `Select > Same > Stroke Color` to find strokes using that swatch

Note I suggest using `Fill Color` and then `Stroke Color` rather than `Fill & Stroke Color` because this will better target the color use. If you have objects with varying fills, but the same stroke color, `Fill & Stroke Color` won't pick up those objects. By specifically targeting the fill color, then the stroke color, you ensure you get all uses of that swatch color.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Scott's answer:

We can change the colors using the Recolor Artwork panel.

This will change the fill and stroke at the same time.

[image]